# php 0x00 breaks preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace `\x00` in a binary file with:

```
preg_replace("/[\x00]/", '', $input);
```

If I have `\x00` anywhere on the pattern preg_replace fails with:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '/' found
```

What is the recommended way to do this?

**Edit**

What I'm actually tring to replace is `\x67\x45\x00\x00([^\xFF]{30})`

but since I've not been able to replace `\x00` the best I can do is `\x67\x45\([^\xFF]{30})`

which is replacing some sequences it shouldn't

Comment: `\x00` is already interpreted in PHP double quoted string context and turns into a `NUL` and thus prematurely cuts the string off before reaching PCRE.

Comment: Why are you trying to replace NUL in the first place?

Comment: found an anwser here http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/498725-preg_match-how-match-x00-null it works ok with single quotes

Comment: @andrew If you use double quotes, you probably need to double escape `\\x00`. Anyways, that's one reason why I tend to go for single quotes.